# Difference between Jupyter Notebook Types

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I have recently started using TensorFlow with GPU support. After following [this](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/The-Best-Way-to-Install-TensorFlow-with-GPU-Support-on-Windows-10-Without-Installing-CUDA-1187/#install-anaconda-python) blog, I have successfully installed TensorFlow-GPU in Jupyter Notebook. But after I open Jupyter Notebook, I get the following 2 notebooks - Python 3 and TensorFlow-GPU.

[image]

I have found multiple blogs that use either of the two  notebooks to implement programs with Tensorflow-GPU support. All I want to know is the difference between the two notebooks. Thanks.

Comment: You have 2 types of kernel... you create as many notebooks as you want using either of these kernels. I'm assuming the `TensorFlow-GPU` kernel is a python3 kernel set up with all the relevant libraries installed and/or relevant environment setup.

Comment: @AChampion The list of libraries shows the same in both kernels.

Comment: Looking at the instructions it looks like it shouldn't as it installs all of the TF libraries into a virtual environment that the `TensforFlow-GPU` is set to run from. I'm assuming the `Python 3` is a stock install. It is possible that both kernels point to the same virtualenv but that seems unlikely and pointless. You can always run `import sys; print(sys.base_prefix)` to see where they are running from or `help('modules')` to see the list of available modules.

Comment: @AChampion It was my mistake. You're right. TensorFlow-GPU kernel has TensorFlow libraries installed and provides GPU support as well. Whereas The Python3 kernel has no default libraries installed and does not provide GPU support. I saw it in https://medium.com/@viveksingh.heritage/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-version-with-jupyter-windows-10-in-8-easy-steps-8797547028a4 blog. He uses the Python3 kernel to implement TensorFlow programs. The installation procedure was the same. I wonder why his Jupyter does not show TensorFlow-GPU kernel.